# Remove everything before the first space in R

Tags: r, regex, substring, gsub

I have tried `gsub` as following to remove everything before the first space but it didn't work.

```
lagl2$SUSPENSE <- gsub(pattern = "(.*)\\s",replace=" ", lagl2$SUSPENSE)
```

example of the row data:    `64400/GL WORKERS COMPENSATION`

and I want the result to be like that: `WORKERS COMPENSATION`

This is just an example but I have many observations and one column and need to delete everything before the first space.

I am new to R and to programming but I started loving it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can remove everything before first space using `sub` as -

```
sub(".*?\\s", "", "64400/GL WORKERS COMPENSATION")
#[1] "WORKERS COMPENSATION"
```

To apply to the whole column you can do -

```
lagl2$SUSPENSE <- sub(".*?\\s", "", lagl2$SUSPENSE)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also assert the start of the string `^` , and match optional non whitespace chars followed by one or more whitespace chars using `\S*\s+` that you want to remove.

```
sub("^\\S*\\s+", "", "64400/GL WORKERS COMPENSATION")
```

Output

```
[1] "WORKERS COMPENSATION"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can match everything before first space using [lookarounds](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

```
/^[^\s]+(?=\s)\s+/gm
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/caARwi/1)